# How to use shared variables Rust's Rocket web framework?

Tags: web, rust, web-applications, webserver, rust-rocket

I'm trying to use shared resources in the routing functions, like accessing the variable "shared_resource" in my hello() function

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let shared_resource = SharedResource::new()
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![hello])
}

#[get("/")]
fn hello() -> &'static str {
    let _ = shared_resource.some_method()
    "Hello, world!"
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`rocket::State`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/struct.State.html) for that.

This will work as long as `SharedResource` implements `Send + Sync + 'static` and is initialized at startup.

### Example

```rust
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let shared_resource = SharedResource::new()
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![hello])
        .manage(shared_resource)
}

#[get("/")]
fn hello(shared_resource: State<SharedResource>) -> &'static str {
    let _ = shared_resource.some_method()
    "Hello, world!"
}
```